# How to fetch change set owner name from IChangeSet object?

Tags: java, api, rtc

I have few of the change set data with me but I need to fetch out the change set owner and component name. Below is the code I am using :

```
IChangeSetHandle changeSets = convertToChangeSetHandles(extracted);

                    if (source instanceof IChangeSetHandle) {
                        changeSet = (IChangeSet) repoApac.itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(changeSets,
                                IItemManager.DEFAULT, monitor);
                    }
    private static IChangeSetHandle convertToChangeSetHandles(String uuidStrings) {
            IChangeSetHandle csh = (IChangeSetHandle)IChangeSet.ITEM_TYPE.createItemHandle(UUID.valueOf(uuidStrings), null);
        return csh;
    }
```

Please help